# html strings in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I feed a string to my textarea.

The string contains HTML strings, such as `&copy;`, `&eacute;`, etc.

I need these strings to be displayed as such (`&copy;`, `&eacute;`) and not be turned into © and é respectively.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape them properly, that is turn `&` into `&amp;` in this case.

Though, if you feed them using the `.value` assignment, your problem is not with `textarea` and your string is deentitified before getting into javascript variable.

Comment: the problem is that I am then submitting the text inside the textarea. So I would then need to change `&amp;` back into `&`?

Comment: Err.. That's exactly what I said, no? Also, I've added another sentence to my answer which may be of interest. You do not really provide enough information about what you're doing.

Comment: I use PHP to get LONGTEXT from MySQL. Then I echo the string into the textarea. The Textarea is inside a `<form>`. When the form gets submitted, it posts the content of the textarea into another PHP script, which writes info into the MySQL. The MySQL must have those HTML characters as HTML characters, not their graphic representation.

Comment: Then you should `<textarea><?=htmlentities($string)?></textarea>` instead.

Comment: Did you notice you tagged your question `javascript`, not `php`? :)

Comment: Michael, that's because I thought there was some very simple way to deal with it on the client side, if not purely by some HTML tag

Comment: If you don't deal with it on the server side, on the client side (that is, after parsing html) you're already in trouble. Moreover, you would also have problems if your string contained something like `<b>bold</b>` too. You should escape entities if you're putting into html the string that you want on the client literally.

Comment: thank you Michael. So I guess I will need to do two conversions - one to display the text inside the textarea and then two after the textarea gets submitted back to php - correct?

Comment: No, I don't think you need to do anything after submission. It gets encoded differently (using url encoding) and php does decode for you.